# Change font size of text under div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

How can i change the size of text under a div element ?

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/giannisf19/v1tu3g62/)

```
$(document).keydown(function (ev){
    if (ev.which == 75 && $("#glass").hasClass("glass"))
    {
        $("#glass").removeClass("glass");
    }

    else if (ev.which == 75 && !$("#glass").hasClass("glass"))
    {
        $("#glass").addClass("glass");
    }

})

$(document).ready( function() {

    $("#glass").addClass("glass");

    $(document).mousemove(function (event) {
            $("#glass").css({
                left: event.pageX,
                top:  event.pageY,
            });

        $("#divX").text(event.pageX);
        $("#divY").text(event.pageY);

    });
});
```

Everything under div with red border must be changed. How can i approach this problem ?

Comment: Your link is a bit wonky.

Comment: For simplicity: http://jsfiddle.net/giannisf19/v1tu3g62/.  You basically want a magnifying glass?  It's not really going to work unless you make the same page twice and slide the offset around as you move.  Question is too generic really.

Comment: @JamesKorden Yes, could you please explain the "slide the offset part"?

Comment: The basics are thus.  You make a second page inside the div that follows the mouse.  This is an exact replica of the page but at twice the size.  Now, when you move the mouse, you slide the contents of the div twice the amount you move your mouse, but in the opposite direction.  This gives the appearance of a magnifying glass.  But I would advise using a pre-made library for this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of libraries for a magnifying glass effect on an image. But if you want this to happen on text, the only way to do this is to have a second hidden div with the same text content with a larger font size, that only appears when you hover over the first text div.

You'd need to do some math to figure out how to show the corresponding part of the magnified div depending where you are hovering over.

I think it would be much easier to use this nice library I found called AnythingZoomer: http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingZoomer/text.php (It is open source too).

Comment: I found anythingzoomer but it only works if theres a div and inside it a p element. If there more p's or some other elements the plugin doesnt work.

Comment: You might be able to add to it since it's open source. Doesn't look like there's anything better out there.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking up a premade option.

For example:

http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/magnifying-glass-for-images-using-jquery-and-css3

While this, and many other examples will use an image, you can always replace the image object with a div, it will just take a lot more construction.  Also, if you don't force a fixed width on your page it will likely fall apart (unless you account for that in the "magnified" div also.